# Regex find number ignoring all non numeric characters

Tags: php, regex

The saved string: `(123) 456-78-90`

The search term: `34567`


What reg expression I need to find a match. Have tried:

```
/3.*4.*5.*6.*7/
```

But if a search term is `34569` it still will find a match which is wrong.


I need regex to find the number in given order but ignoring all between these numbers like brackets, spaces or dashes.


Thank you

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you need. Is it the 1234567890 out of  The saved string: (123) 456-78-90

Comment: Try [`if (strpos(preg_replace('~\D+~', '', $s), $search) > -1) { echo "Found match!"; }`](https://ideone.com/nyjNys)

Comment: Where are the saved strings, DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `.` to `\D` (non-numbers) and it will work, e.g. `/3\D*4\D*5\D*6\D*7/`

Comment: Big thank you. But for some reason `\D*` does not work with my rest api so I had to replace it with `[^0-9]*` then it worked well.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just remove the non numerical characters and then search on that:

```
$input = "(123) 456-78-90";
$input = preg_replace("/[^0-9]+/", "", $input);
if (strpos($input, '34567') !== false) {
    echo 'match';
}
```

### Demo

Comment: Yes, same as my suggestion [in the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51401197/regex-find-number-ignoring-all-non-numeric-characters#comment89773083_51401197). But note that `i` modifier is redundant here.

Comment: thank you for your answer but I'm not able to touch php side. I needed a regex as a string for rest api request.

Comment: @Mark in that case you tagged the wrong language. From your other comment sounds like you are running a non-PCRE regex.